# slash are removed from jquery ajax post data

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "DataImport.aspx/InsertInitialFile",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                processData: false,
                data: '{"companyId":"' + "1" + '","importFileName":"' + "license.txt" + '","filePath":"' + "UploadFolder\Initial\Temprahullate" + '","importStatusId":"' + "5" + '"}',

                //data: '{"companyId":"' + companyId + '","importFileName":"' + importFileName + '","filePath":"' + filePath + '","importStatusId":"' + importStatusId + '"}',
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (Msg) {
                    $("#<%= upload_Initialfilename.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%= ddlCompany.ClientID %>").val("0");
                    $('#<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>').html("File saved successfully.");
                    $("#<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>").css("color", "Green");
                },
                error: function (Msg) {
                    console.log(Msg);
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

I am trying following code to call a web method using jquery ajax . its working OK when i post data manually static as in above code its

```
 data: '{"companyId":"' + "1" + '","importFileName":"' + "license.txt" + '","filePath":"' + "UploadFolder\Initial\Temprahullate" + '","importStatusId":"' + "5" + '"}',
```

but the real problem is when i check data on server side for `filePath` field , its remove the slashes from its . means instead of this **`UploadFolder\Initial\Temprahullate`** i get **`UploadFolderInitialTemprahullate`** in server side method.

I need those slashes as that is path of folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character in Javascript is an escape character. To get a single `\` into your string, you actually need to use `\\`. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DataImport.aspx/InsertInitialFile",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false,
            data: '{"companyId":"' + "1" + '","importFileName":"' + "license.txt" + '","filePath":"' + "UploadFolder\\Initial\\Temprahullate" + '","importStatusId":"' + "5" + '"}',

            //data: '{"companyId":"' + companyId + '","importFileName":"' + importFileName + '","filePath":"' + filePath + '","importStatusId":"' + importStatusId + '"}',
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (Msg) {
                $("#<%= upload_Initialfilename.ClientID %>").val("");
                $("#<%= ddlCompany.ClientID %>").val("0");
                $('#<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>').html("File saved successfully.");
                $("#<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>").css("color", "Green");
            },
            error: function (Msg) {
                console.log(Msg);
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Comment: if i put \\ slash there then its generate 500 internal server and message is realted to escape string .

Comment: Does the 500 internal server error happen when you initially attempt to load the page, or when you submit the AJAX request?

Comment: when i submit the page the AJax request.